# How to turn dataset into multiple different color lines in D3.JS

Tags: d3.js

Single Line Working with following Dataset:

```
 var dataset = [{ x: 0, y: 100  }, { x: 1, y: 833  }, { x: 2, y: 1312 },
                { x: 3, y: 1222 }, { x: 4, y: 1611 },]
                       ]
```

Multi Line dataset (Which produces no line)

```
  var dataset = [{ x: 0, y: 100  }, { x: 1, y: 833  }, { x: 2, y: 1312 },
                 { x: 3, y: 1222 }, { x: 4, y: 1611 },
                 { x: 0, y: 200  }, { x: 1, y: 933  }, { x: 2, y: 1412 },
                 { x: 3, y: 1322 }, { x: 4, y: 1711 },]
```

This is the D3.JS Code, which works for one line but doesn't produce a second line. What would be the best modification to make to this code so I can pass in the multiline dataset with up to 10 series of data. Also what is the best way to have each line be a different color?

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d.x; })])
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d.y; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(0)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(0);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.y); });

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("#visualisation")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)

svg.append("path")
    .data([dataset])
    .attr("class", "line0")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: To D3 your dataset it's just one with wrong format. Need to tell D3 which data its a set. Need to separate data on differents sets. Look at this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `dataset`, which is an array of points, needs to become **an array of arrays** of points:

```
var dataset = [
  [{ x: 0, y: 100  }, { x: 1, y: 833  }, { x: 2, y: 1312 }, { x: 3, y: 1222 }, { x: 4, y: 1611 }],
  [{ x: 0, y: 200  }, { x: 1, y: 933  }, { x: 2, y: 1412 }, { x: 3, y: 1322 }, { x: 4, y: 1711 }]
]
```

Subsequently, your x and y max calculations for the x and y domains need to find the max across all arrays of points. So they have to gain a level of nested-ness like this:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(series) {
     return d3.max(series, function (d) { return d.x; })
  })])
  .range([0, width]);
```

(Same idea for `yScale`)

Finally, now that there are multiple lines, you should use `d3.selection` with `.enter()` to create one `<path>` per series, like so:

```
svg.selectAll("path.line").data(dataset).enter()
  .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Here's a [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvrL3ey5/)

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for. Is there a small modification that I can make to my dataset to include a legend, and then add the legend to the chart? (I assume making the lines a random color would be part of adding a legend)